# Can I connect NiFi docker container to a HBase container over a docker user defined bridge network?

Tags: networking, hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi, docker-container

**My objective**:

Use NiFi running on a HDF docker container to store data into HBase running on an HDP docker container.

**Progress**:

I am running two docker containers: NiFi and HBase. I have configured NiFi's PutHBaseJSON processor to write data to HBase (puthbasejson_configuration.png).
Below are the configurations I updated in the processor:

```
PutHBaseJSON = HBase_1_1_2_ClientService
Table Name = publictrans
Row Identifier Field Name = Vehicle_ID
Row Identifier Encoding Strategy = String
Column Family = trafficpatterns
Batch Size = 25
Complex Field Strategy = Text
Field Encoding Strategy = String
```

HBase Client Service

I also configured the NiFi's hbase client service on that processor, so NiFi knows which IP address Zookeeper is located at to ask Zookeeper to tell it where HBase Master is (hbaseclientservice_configuration.png).

Configure Controller Service for HBaseClient:

```
ZooKeeper Quorum = 172.25.0.3
ZooKeeper Client Port = 2181
ZooKeeper ZNode Parent = /hbase-unsecure
HBase Client Retries = 1
```

**Problem**:

The problem I am facing is that NiFi is unable to make the connection to HBase Master. I get the following message: failed to invoke "@OnEnabled method due to ... hbase.client.RetriesExhausted Exception ... hbase.MasterNotRunningException ... java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused." Visual of hbaseclientservice at ([hbaseMasterNotRunningException Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzq80.png)).

**Configurations I made to troubleshoot the problem**:

In HDF container, I updated /etc/hosts with 172.25.0.3 -> hdp.hortonworks.com. In HDP container, I updated the hosts file with 172.25.0.2 -> hdf.hortonworks.com. So both containers are aware of each others hostnames.

I port forwarded the needed ports for NiFi, Zookeeper and HBase when I built the HDF and HDP containers. I checked if all ports on HBase were exposed on the HDP container and the image shows all the ports HDP is listening in on including HBase's ports ([ports_hdp_listening_on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI84N.png).png). Here is an image of all ports needed by HBase, I filtered for port keyword in Ambari (hbase_ports_needed.png).

16000 and 16020 ports both looked suspicious since all others had pattern :::port but those two ports had some wording preceding it. So, I checked if I could make the connection to HDP from HDF using telnet 172.25.0.3 16000 and received the output:

Trying 172.25.0.3...

Connected to 172.25.0.3.

Escape character is '^]'.

So I was able to connect to HDP container.

**hbaseMasterNotRunningException Stack Trace**:

```
2017-01-25 22:23:03,342 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-7] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode HBase_1_1_2_ClientService[id=d3eaf393-0159-1000-ffff-ffffa95f1940] Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method due to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=1, exceptions:
Wed Jan 25 22:23:03 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1485382983338, pause=100, retries=1}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2017-01-25 22:23:03,348 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-7] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=1, exceptions:
Wed Jan 25 22:23:03 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1485382983338, pause=100, retries=1}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:147) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:3917) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTableNames(HBaseAdmin.java:413) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTableNames(HBaseAdmin.java:397) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.nifi.hbase.HBase_1_1_2_ClientService.onEnabled(HBase_1_1_2_ClientService.java:187) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor568.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:47) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceNode$2.run(StandardControllerServiceNode.java:345) ~[na:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1533) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1553) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1704) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124) ~[na:na]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:223) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:50918) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1564) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1502) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1524) ~[na:na]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:424) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:748) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:920) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:889) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1222) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213) ~[na:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
2017-01-25 22:23:03,348 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-7] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of HBase_1_1_2_ClientService[id=d3eaf393-0159-1000-ffff-ffffa95f1940] due to org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=1, exceptions:
Wed Jan 25 22:23:03 UTC 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1485382983338, pause=100, retries=1}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

**I am currently still dealing with problem**:

Has anyone setup NiFi HDF docker container to store data into HBase HDP docker container?